# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value- frame wrapping (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting a wrapping error for the example below. Not sure how to safely wrap this, any suggestions?

```
   let frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 150)
        let pickerView = AKPickerView(frame : frame)
        //breaks here
        self.pickerView.delegate = self
        self.pickerView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: There are about 100 'found nil while unwrapping an Optional' questions w/ answers.  Why are none of them appropriate?  Probably AKPickerView() returns an optional of some sort - but w/o more info anything is a guess.

Comment: `self.pickerView` is an implicitly unwrapped optional that is `nil` when that code runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, tested working in my code

```
let frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 150)
let pickerView = AKPickerView(frame : frame)
pickerView.delegate = self
pickerView.dataSource = self
pickerView.reloadData()
self.view.addSubview(pickerView)
```

I have used objective-c AKPickerView with bridging header.

Comment: Thanks I ended up bridging obj-c AKPickerView

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, 150)
if let pickerView = AKPickerView(frame : frame)
{
    self.pickerView.delegate = self
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: I tried this before posting, says bound value in a conditional binding must be of optional type.